Erasing disk and Installing Ubuntu blocked by bitwarden
Trying to install ubuntu 24.04. Installer stopped at "erase disk and install" by bitwarden (no key). How can I just erase entire disk and continue install

Are you a Bitwarden customer?

In a live session, open a terminal, run in it: sudo fdisk -l, copy and paste the output into your post, editing it.

fdisk: cannot open 1: No such file or directory
